# Why can't I get the output in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, output

```
 def travel():
   travel.s=0
   travel.frate=[]
   travel.tr=[]
   def accomodation():                       
                                         print"""specialises
                                         1.place 1
                                         a.hotel 1
                                         b.hotel 2
                                         Hotel1:ac/non ac rooms
                                         Ac.for ac...
                                         Noac.for non ac...."""
                                         hd=[5000,6000]
                                         hg=[4000,7000]
                                         TAc=[1000]
                                         Nac=[400]
                                         ch5=input("Enter your choice")
                                         fav=raw_input("ENter hotel choice")
                                         mode=raw_input("Enter ac/no ac")
                                         if(ch5==1):
                                                for i in hd:
                                                       frate=hd[i]+TAc

                                                else:
                                                       frate=hd[i]+Nac
                                         if(ch5==2):
                                                for i in range(0,2,1):
                                                       frate=hg[i]+TAc
                                                else:
                                                       frate=hg[i]+Nac
  accomodation()
travel()
```

When i run the program , i get the error as List Index out of range.but in hd and hg list,there are only two elements, so index number will be from 0 right?? Is there anything i should import?? I even gave statements like this:

```
  travel.frate=travel.hg[i]+TAc
```

but it still doesn't come.Thank you for your effort.
the indentation is proper now,but the output is still not coming.

Comment: please fix your indentation - 4 spaces per step. Also, you're missing a closing `"""` somewhere...

Comment: please help<the indentation is proper now

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7, have you looked at your Q?  Indentation's pretty broken still.  Further, besides fixing it, also post a proper stack trace for your exception which will clarify exactly where it occurs.

Comment: you haven't edited your question, therefore nothing has been fixed. Please click this [edit] link to fix your code, and add the **entire text** of any errors or tracebacks you're getting.

Comment: now the indentation is proper,but error is"list index out of range"

Comment: @Animeartistfromhell7:  You need to make sure that each level of indentation is 4 spaces long, no more, no less ([a standard convention in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: After that, you need to look at the code you posted, and notice that most or it is in brown.  That means most of it is actually just a text string, because you have `"""` immediately after your `print` statement that you don't close.  You need to fix that.

Comment: Finally, the Python interpreter splits out a long error message that looks like `Traceback (most recent call last): \n File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> \n IndexError: list index out of range` (insert real line breaks instead of `\n`).  You need to always post the entirety of that message in your questions, because that will tell the answerers a lot about what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @zehnpaard,sorry for the mistake,but it still doesn't come

Comment: You do need to do the other two things as well (correct the indents, and post the stack trace)

Comment: what"s a stack trace??

Comment: The long error message that I mention in my comment "Finally, the Python interpreter..."

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\My Ssss... Files\sec5.py", line 30, in accomodation
    frate=hd[i]+TAc
   IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue you are encountering is caused by these lines here:

```
if(ch5==1):
    for i in hd:
        frate=hd[i]+TAc
```

`hd[i]` looks at `hd[5000]` and `hd[6000]` which will throw an IndexError.

But if you fix that, you're going to run into another error, because

```
frate=hd[i]+TAc
```

tries to add a list `TAc` to an integer `hd[i]`, which is an unsupported operation.  You probably need `frate=hd[i]+TAc[0]`, or even better, make `TAc` a number rather than a list.  This issue occurs elsewhere in your code as well.

Finally, while not causing explicit issues in your code right now, there are two other problems:

1. `ch5=input("Enter your choice")` is dangerous since `input` tells Python to run whatever code snippet the user enters.  In this case, much safer to do `ch5=int(raw_input("Enter your choice"))`
2. `for i in range(0,2,1):` is really `for i in range(2):` - only use the starting index and jump parameters if you need to change them from their default, namely 0 and 1.

There are other issues like variable scope (you're expecting travel.frate to be modified from within accommodation, but that's not happening) and defining variables in functions like `travel.frate` (not invalid syntax, but definitely strange) but those are probably better addressed outside of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your hardwork!
I m new to python and i really needed this help!